# How do I assign an integer in a line in a text file to a variable in c?

Tags: c, pointers, file-handling, turbo-c

I have a text file in which numbers were fed by fprintf("%d\n",var); Now the structure of file is:
number 1
number 2
number 3
number 4 etc
i want to assign number 1 to var_x,number 2 to var_y,number 3 to var_z then print all variables then assign number 4 to var 1 and so on How do i do it?

I tried sscanf fscanf etc. but it just prints random numbers

this is how i am filling numbers in the file:

```
      fprintf(save_file,"%d\n",xaxis);
      fprintf(save_file,"%d\n",yaxis);
      fprintf(save_file,"%d\n",getpixel(xaxis,yaxis));
```

this how the result file looks like:

```
30
20
0
31
21
15
32
22
0 etc
```

this is what i am trying right now:

```
sscanf(open_file,"%d",&read_x);
sscanf(open_file,"%d",&read_y);
sscanf(open_file,"%d",&read_colour);
while(!feof(open_file))
{
   printf("%d %d %d",read_x,read_y,read_colour);
   sscanf(open_file,"%d",read_x);
   sscanf(open_file,"%d",read_y);
   sscanf(open_file,"%d",read_colour);

}
```

expected result is:

```
30 20 0
31 21 15
32 22 0
```

Comment: You're trying to read a file with a function (`sscanf`) that reads a string. Try `fscanf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fscanf all 3 values at once:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("input", "r");

    int x, y, z;

    while (fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z) > 0)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: can you help me with one more thing? when i am creating a file it is being saved in capital letters eg:file.txt becomes FILE.TXT in the directory

Comment: You're welcome! Never seen this kind of 'error', how are you creating the file?

Comment: not sure how it is saving in upper case but it is not hurting the functionality .I can open the file even by passing file name in lowercase .

Comment: If you're using fopen and passing the name of the file in lowercase, it will create the file with a lower case name. Maybe it is the program you are using to view the files that is displaying the uppercase name. What OS are you using?